# Does prepared statement protect me from seeing garbage in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Basically I started to use prepared statements after I've read some articles on the internet which said that it's an easy way to prevent sql injection. Jumping to my scenario, I have a logExit function which inserts into the DB the page that the visitor came from on my website and the page where he is going after leaving my website.

```
public function logExit($url){
    $HTTP_REFERER = ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '');    
    $REMOTE_ADDR = ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '');

    $params = array(
        $REMOTE_ADDR,
        $HTTP_REFERER,
        $url
    );

    // custom query function ~ prepare/execute
    $this->query("
        INSERT INTO exits(ip, url_in, url_out) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ", "sss", $params);
}
```

The thing is that, today when I logged into the admin panel to check how many visitors did I had today and where did they left from my website, I got tons of alerts. When I checked my database I had like 13500 exits from the same IP to different pages but the issue came from the `url_in` field, here are some examples:

```
     ip    |               url_in                |    url_out    |
-----------+-------------------------------------+---------------|
  xx.xx.xx |'"></a><script>alert(11779)</script> | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
-----------+-------------------------------------+---------------|
  xx.xx.xx |            ,alert(11774),           | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
-----------|-------------------------------------|---------------|
  xx.xx.xx |                %c0%a7               | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
-----------|-------------------------------------|---------------|
  xx.xx.xx |                 %2527               | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
-----------+-------------------------------------+---------------|
```

> HTTP_REFERER = url_in
>
> $url = url_out

So this seem to be strange because as far as I know the HTTP_REFERER should be an URL. How did this mess get into my database and how to prevent it?

Thanks

PS. The hosting company showed me this log, what does it mean?

```
access-logs/my-example-website.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx - - [21/Dec/2017:18:59:59 +0200] "GET /mode.php?admin_mode=1&referer=javascript:alert(16555) HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Comment: Is your website connected through a load balancer, router, cache, or other IP-obscuring device?

Comment: Thats not sql injection. Thats just garbage in being escaped safely so it gets stored without overrunning your full SQL query. Which I'm guessing your admin tool then simply outputting in html for you to read, which executed the javascript scripts in the data fields. Fun times!

Comment: @IncredibleHat - Well, not quite, the first line added a script into my page and when I open the admin pannel I get thousands of alerts. Is that safely escaped ?

Comment: Read the answer below by tadman.

Comment: @wallyk - IDK, it's on a shared hosting server. I have to ask the company. Why do you ask? Do you think that they can do more for me ? Or I should do more for my self ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But I think you bind HTTP_REFERER to url_in, and not REMOTE_ADDR. Remote_addr should be trustworthy in almost all situations (doesn't hurt to make sure it's in IP), but the referrer is controlled by the client/attacker, and should not be trusted at all.

Comment: @jh1711 HTTP_REFERER = url_in; $url = url_out

Comment: `mode.php?admin_mode=1&referer=javascript:alert(16555)` it was trying to pop an `alert(16555)` out. Hoping there would a code like `echo $_GET['referer']`. Since the response is 404, i might say a tool with tons of slugs performing such xss attack is targeting your site.

Comment: Yes. So the funky stuff in `url_in` are no surprise. The first two rows are attempts at XSS. The third is invalid utf8. not sure what it's probing for. The fourth could be a (non working) attempt at SQLi, or an attack against WordPress <4.8.4.

Comment: This are just a few of the lines, there were many other attepts.

Comment: I guess I did not read carefully enough until now. Do you actually get lots of nonsensical javascript alerts, that you have to click, and finally tell your browser to stop executing them? If that's the case some of the Cross Site Scripting vectors are successful. And that's something to worry about. If the referrer is the only entry point, @O. Jones answer should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes I get alerts into the browser, and I have to click OK hundreds of times to stop them all. This is due to the fact that inside my database it got <script>alert(...)</script>

Answer (score 7):

This is working as designed, you're protected from SQL injection problems. The key thing here is SQL injection attacks are just [one vector of many](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page).

In order to safely use that content you **must** escape it properly for the context in which it's used. If you're displaying that as HTML that means using a function like [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent XSS attacks, or if you're encoding that in JSON or JavaScript then using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to properly encode it for that context.

If you're seeing junk like that in your database it's probably because you're being probed by some automated attacker. Most production sites will see tens of thousands of attack attempts per day, and sadly this is just how things are. If you'd like to quiet things down you can use things like [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/) to ban repeat offenders.

Comment: Someone probing your system, probably. They seem to be looking for XSS vectors.

Answer (score 2):

That you see those results in your table, and not a series of errors in your error log complaining about malformed SQL shows that the prepared statement + bound variables is doing its job.

Please note that it's not the prepared statement that protects you from SQL injection, but the use of bound variables rather than building SQL statements from dirty data.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare statement is the best way to safe you from sql injections (you should use a wide used framework but i guess this is the case here)

Prepared statements will not prevent you from getting garbage data into the database. Even attack vectors which could be succeed later when interprated f.e. as html (xss) could get into the database. But in this case the root cause is a missing validation/escaping before rendering and not the database framework.

However to archive clean data in the database you have to validate the data before you insert them (input validation). And let me tell you there is no easy way to accomplish this for all data because it depends on the nature of the information you have in your particular application. And there is no silver bullet for this.

Answer (score 1):

Others are right. You have successfully avoided SQL injection.

But cybercreeps are sending you maliciously crafted referer strings.

You know the HTTP "referer" header is supposed to contain a URL. The remote address string is supposed to contain an ip address or hostname, with a port number attached. (not a URL).

So, before you insert referer into your database you can check it to see whether it's a well formed URL or something malicious. If it's malicious you can just blank it, or change it to http://malicious.example.com, or do whatever you want to get rid of the rubbish, before you INSERT it.

In your case, use [php's nice built in filtering capability](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). Add these lines right after you set `$HTTP_REFERER` for the first time.

```
 $HTTP_REFERER  = filter_var( $HTTP_REFERER, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE );
 if ( is_null( $HTTP_REFERER ) ) {
    $HTTP_REFERER = 'http://bogus-referer.example.com/';
 }
```

or something.

Do something similar for remote_addr, using FILTER_VALIDATE_IP.

And remember this: you're not paranoid. Clever and motivated people are actually plotting against you, and trying to pwn your web site.

Comment: Come on, don't make a drama. It's just stupid bots run by script kiddies  who are trying their luck with a broad fishnet. If you happen to own a website, just take a peek into access log - you'll see a complete collection of such  junk.